# Positioning divs equally within a container

Tags: css, grid, positioning

I am having some problems trying to equally position 5 divs inline across within a container div.

I have created a demo [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9HdUt/)

I am having a problem with the hover over too (the demo isn't behaving correctly) But with the css to fade in on the hover instead of just appearing.

so this is my css for the grid and container:

```
.span_5_of_5 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_4_of_5 {
    width: 79.68%;
}
.span_3_of_5 {
    width: 59.36%;
}
.span_2_of_5 {
    width: 39.04%;
}
.span_1_of_5 {
    width: 18.72%;
}


.containeralt{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Any help at this point would be most appreciated.

Comment: change `display:block` to `display:inline-block` for your css hover element ... http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/9HdUt/1/

Comment: @mostafaznv hey man thanks for the answer but the issue isnt with the position of the popup (they work on my real-time version) it is the fade in of them. the main issue is actually the position of the 5 divs  across the container.

Comment: i don't understand ... :/ Please delete extra codes in your DEMO

Comment: So the 5 divs across the middle which are two circles and a square. I need them to sit equally across with the same margin in between each div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behaviour that you're after can be achieved with the use of `text-align:center;` and `display:inline-block;`

I've stripped down alot of your HTML to the basics, as there was alot of unused `<spans>` and even a `<center>`, unsued classes, extra code probably used in some unposted Javascript etc... Not sure what's going on there so I removed anything unecessary, here's the basics of what I think you're after:

HTML:

```
<div id="imgDiv3">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p class="circletext">APPS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p class="circletext">WEB DESIGN</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="tabletouter">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p class="circletext">MOBILE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <p class="circletext">PC/MAC</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.circle {
    border-radius: 60px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #3B5163;
}

div.tabletouter {
    width: 295px;
    height: 354px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #3B5163;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.circletext {
    font-family:"museo-slab";
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #666666;
}

#imgDiv3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 20px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uwjC7/